# What is the best practice for building deeply-embedded DSL in Scala?

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, programming-languages, interpreter, dsl

Deeply-embedded DSL means building DSL AST in hosting languages(Scala) without parser.

However, directly writing nested case class is very tedious [e.g. Let(NewVar(x), (Add (NumLit 1) (NumLit 2)), Call(Var(f) List(Var(x))))]

Comment: There's not enough detail here to understand what you're really asking,

Comment: I understand the question, but I don't think I have a good answer. A sketch of it might be to use implicit conversions for leaf nodes and infix methods for internal, binary nodes. For other type of nodes, I don't know...

Comment: See these http://blog.scalac.io/2015/05/07/encog-dsl.html http://codetunes.com/2012/scala-dsl-tutorial-writing-web-framework-router/

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan thanks, these suggestions are really good.

Comment: "writing nest case class is very tedious..."   *That's why you use a parser*.   This isn't for Scala, but you can see how a modern program transformation system lets you write patterns for code fragments conveniently: http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSRewriteRules.htm.  This would be the right way to do it for Scala, but it is a lot of work.